# Automapper Enum Description Attribute

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having difficulties mapping from an Enum Description Attribute.  I've been looking all over for a useful example with very little luck.  I know there are some other examples out there but I'm still struggling with this particular scenario.

Here is my Enum:

```
public enum ResolveCodeEnum
{
    [Description("Resolved - Workaround")]
    ResolvedWorkaround = 1,
    [Description("Resolved - Permanently")]
    ResolvedPermanently = 2,
    [Description("Resolved - Unknown")]
    ResolvedUnkown = 3,
    [Description("Cannot Reproduce")]
    CannotReproduce = 4,
    [Description("Invalid")]
    Invalid = 5,
    [Description("Cancelled")]
    Cancelled = 6
}
```

Here is my Enum Helper class:

```
public class EnumHelper
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

My goal is to map source to destination via Enum Description Attribute

Here is what I have so far in my mapping configuration:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Result, Incident>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Status,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.state));
```

Here is the abbreviated Result class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the abbreviated Incident class:

```
public class Incident
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Status{ get; set; }
}
```

Note:  the state property of the Result class is a string

For example:

My goal is to get

```
 Incident.Status = "Resolved - Workaround"
```

From

```
 Result.state = "1"
```

I've been struggle with the automapper syntax to use with my EnumHelper class

If anybody can help me out on this, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show the definitions of the Result and Incident classes?

Comment: @Justin Harvey, I've added more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Inline with `ResolveUsing`:

   ```
       Mapper.CreateMap<Result, Incident>()
           .ForMember(
               dest => dest.Status,
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
               {
                   var value = (ResolveCodeEnum)Enum.Parse(
                                   typeof(ResolveCodeEnum), src.state);

                   return EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription(value);
               }));
   ```
2. With a custom `ValueResolver`:

   ```
   public class EnumValueResolver : ValueResolver<Result, string>
   {
       protected override string ResolveCore(Result src)
       {
           var value = (ResolveCodeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ResolveCodeEnum), src.state);

           return EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription(value);    
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Result, Incident>()
       .ForMember(
           dest => dest.Status,
           opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EnumValueResolver>());
   ```

I'd recommend #2 since it's much cleaner.

Comment: I've tried both of these and still get this exception: "Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression"

Comment: @BBauer42: That sounds like it might possibly be related to Entity Framework or another ORM. If that's the case it might be worth opening a new question.

Comment: Yeah, its EF and its during a queryable projection. I'm opening a question thanks.