# c# - Enum description to string with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, automapper, projection

I'm trying to project from my `Order` model to my `OrderDTO` model. `Order` has an enum. The problem is that projection doesn't work if I try to to get the *Description* attribute from the Enum. Here it's my code:

- **OrderStatus.cs**:

  ```
  public enum OrderStatus {
      [Description("Paid")]
      Paid,

      [Description("Processing")]
      InProcess,

      [Description("Delivered")]
      Sent
  }
  ```
- **Order.cs**:

  ```
  public class Order {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
      public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- **OrderDTO.cs**:

  ```
  public class OrderDTO {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public List<OrderLineDTO> OrderLines { get; set; }
      public string Status { get; set; }  
  }
  ```

With this following configuration in my **AutoMapper.cs**:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>().ForMember(
    dest => dest.Status,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status.ToString())
);
```

Projection works, but I get an **OrderDTO** object like this:

```
 - Id: 1
 - OrderLines: List<OrderLines>
 - Sent //I want "Delivered"!
```

I don't want `Status` property to be "Sent", I want it to be as its associated *Description* attribute, in this case, "Delivered".

I have tried two solutions and none of them have worked:

1. Using *ResolveUsing* AutoMapper function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711134/automapper-enum-description-attribute), but, as it's stated [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2334#issuecomment-332191644):

> ResolveUsing is not supported for projections, see the wiki on LINQ projections for supported operations.

2. Using a static method to return the *Description* attribute in String by Reflection.

   ```
   cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>().ForMember(
       dest => dest.Status,
       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => EnumHelper<OrderStatus>.GetEnumDescription(src.Status.ToString()))
   );
   ```

But this gives me the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetEnumDescription(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Then, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just thinking outside of the box, can't you just rename your enum `Sent` to `Delivered` like the description?. Also, having a distinction between `Sent` and `Delivered` would be nice because they are two different states.

Comment: @jmesolomon That doesn't matter. It's just an example I thought

Comment: @Sergio see this answer, this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434045/3901530

Comment: There is no easy way to do that with ProjectTo, but you can look into [NeinLinq](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extension method like this one (borrowed the logic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public string GetDescription(this OrderStatus This)
    {
        var type = typeof(OrderStatus);
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(This.ToString());
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
    }
}
```

Then access it in your map:

```
cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
    .ForMember
    (
        dest => dest.Status,
        opt => opt.MapFrom
        (
            src => src.Status.GetDescription()
        )
    );
}
```

This results in what you are asking for:

```
Console.WriteLine(dto.Status);  //"Delivered", not "sent"
```

[See a working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y68UAl)

**Edit1**: Don’t think you can add a local look up function like that to LINQ to entities. It would only work in LINQ to objects. The solution you should pursue perhaps is a domain table in the database that allows you to join to it and return the column that you want so that you don’t have to do anything with AutoMapper.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I need to access the parameters of the custom attribute

Comment: This example shows you how to implement and access a parameter named Description. You ought you’ve able to adapt it to your own attribute with its own parameters.

Comment: Thanks didn’t realize

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JohnWu. I've implemented your extension method, apply it to my AutoMapper.cs, but I keep receiveing this error:
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetOrderStatusDescription(...Enums.OrderStatus)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`. I have uploaded an image with my code [here](https://i.imgur.com/7oe31V6.png) so that you can check it out. Thanks

Comment: Don’t think you can add a local look up function like that to LINQ to entities. It would only work in LINQ to objects. The solution you should pursue perhaps is a domain table in the database that allows you to join to it and return the column that you want so that you don’t have to do anything with AutoMapper.

Comment: Alright @JohnWu. Thank you for your time. I'm going to accept and edit your answer with your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve an expression based enum description mapping by building up an expression that evaluates to a string containing a condition statement (such as switch/if/case depending on how the provider implements it) with the enum descriptions as the results.

Because the enum descriptions can be extracted ahead of time we can obtain them and use them as a constant for the result of the condition expression.

**Note:** I've used the above extension method **GetDescription()** but you can use whatever flavour of attribute extraction you need.

```
  public static Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> CreateEnumDescriptionExpression<TEntity, TEnum>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TEnum>> propertyExpression)
     where TEntity : class
     where TEnum : struct
  {
     // Get all of the possible enum values for the given enum type
     var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<Enum>();

     // Build up a condition expression based on each enum value
     Expression resultExpression = Expression.Constant(string.Empty);
     foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
     {
        resultExpression = Expression.Condition(
           Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(enumValue)),
           // GetDescription() can be replaced with whatever extension 
           // to get you the needed enum attribute.
           Expression.Constant(enumValue.GetDescription()),
           resultExpression);
     }

     return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, string>>(
        resultExpression, propertyExpression.Parameters);
  }
```

Then your Automapper mapping becomes:

```
  cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>().ForMember(
     dest => dest.Status, opts => opts.MapFrom(
             CreateEnumDescriptionExpression<Order, OrderStatus>(src => src.Status)));
```

When this is evaluated at runtime using Entity Framework with SQL server provider, the resulting SQL will be something like:

```
SELECT 
   -- various fields such as Id
   CASE WHEN (2 = [Extent1].[Status]) THEN N'Delivered' 
        WHEN (1 = [Extent1].[Status]) THEN N'Processing' 
        WHEN (0 = [Extent1].[Status]) THEN N'Paid' ELSE N'' END AS [C1]
FROM [Orders] as [Extent1]
```

This should also work for other Entity Framework DB providers.

Comment: If you want, you can more closely integrate it with AM. See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Projection/BindersAndResultConverters.cs).

Comment: Although a map from `Enum` to `string` would probably fit better.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for the insight into AutoMapper cfg.Advanced.QueryableBinders - I'll take a look. Would be nice not to specify the expression converter for each property.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Not sure your meaning of "Enum to string would probably fit better"?

Comment: A map would apply everywhere, for every `Enum` converted to string, so you don't need to specify it for each property.

Comment: Excellent solution!  I was about to build my own custom expression if I don't found this one.